# Android: two edittext changeable, error on the second

Tags: android, android-edittext, onchange

I have this code:

```
    final EditText kcalh=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.kcalh_inserisci);
    final EditText kw=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.kw_inserisci);
    kcalh.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            int risultato=Integer.parseInt(kcalh.getText().toString())/860;
            kw.setText(""+risultato);
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,int arg2, int arg3) {}
     });
    kw.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            int risultato=Integer.parseInt(kw.getText().toString())*860;
            kcalh.setText(""+risultato);
            System.out.println(risultato);
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,int arg2, int arg3) {}
     });
```

when i change the first edittext, all work correctly (the second edittext change it's value... when i use the second the app crash.
you know why?
i think it goes into the aftertext of the first and crash... but why not in the second also?

Comment: what is the eroor log showing?

Comment: post the damn logcat. why it is not obvious?!

Comment: because it's not needed, it's an obvious error. and the logcat it's sooo long.
i've solved it putting .hasFocus inside the afterTextChanged

Comment: Did you really post a question then complain when someone asks to post the logcat that it's an obvious error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check EditText for empty before parsing  String to Integer:

```
kw.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            if(kw.getText().toString().length() > 0){
              int risultato=Integer.parseInt(kw.getText().toString())*860;
               kcalh.setText(""+risultato);
               System.out.println(""+risultato);
           }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,int arg2, int arg3) {}
     });
```